# Am I forced to use 2 headers or what is the way using one

Tags: c++11, gcc, forward-declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <deque>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

class session_elem;
typedef std::map<std::string, session_elem> autosession;
union session_elem_t{
    std::string s;
    int64_t n;
    char c;
    std::function<void(autosession*)> f;
    autosession r;
};
class session_elem{
    enum type{ s, n, c, f, r };
    session_elem_t val;
};
typedef std::map<std::string, session_elem> autosession;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a solution out of this puzzle ?

Depending on the order, I get a forward declaration error.

What order of declaration must I use for my code to compile under GCC 5.3 ?

I can't be more minimal than this and it still fails to compile. Everything seems right tome so why is there a forward declaration error ?

error given is

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j8 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ ArchiUtils - Debug ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/archivist/Projets/zdd/ArchiUtils/ArchiUtils'
codelite-cc /usr/bin/g++  -c  "/home/archivist/Projets/zdd/ArchiUtils/ArchiUtils/main.cpp" -pedantic -std=c++14 -Wall -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5.3.1/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5.3.1/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5.3.1/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5.3.1/iostream:39,
                 from /home/archivist/Projets/zdd/ArchiUtils/ArchiUtils/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of 'struct std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ArchiUtils::v1::sv0::session_elem>':
/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/functional:1981:45:   required by substitution of 'template<class _Functor, class> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = std::function<void(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, ArchiUtils::v1::sv0::session_elem>*)>; <template-parameter-1-2> = <missing>]'
/home/archivist/Projets/zdd/ArchiUtils/ArchiUtils/ArchiUtils.hpp:1003:10:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_pair.h:102:11: error: 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second' has incomplete type
       _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
           ^
In file included from /home/archivist/Projets/zdd/ArchiUtils/ArchiUtils/main.cpp:2:0:
/home/archivist/Projets/zdd/ArchiUtils/ArchiUtils/ArchiUtils.hpp:1003:10: note: forward declaration of 'class ArchiUtils::v1::sv0::session_elem'
    class session_elem{
          ^
ArchiUtils.mk:95: recipe for target 'Debug/main.cpp.o' failed
make[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/archivist/Projets/zdd/ArchiUtils/ArchiUtils'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
make: *** [All] Error 2
====4 errors, 3 warnings====
```

Comment: The code you have compiles just fine on GCC 5.3. What is the problem?

Comment: It gives me an Error Forward declaration of ... see i update

Comment: Also on GCC 5.3, and I can confirm that the code you posted above compiles with no errors or warnings on -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic. What is the specific error message you're getting, and is it possible that it's not actually related to this code?

Comment: Please post the error message you see.

Comment: @acwaters Done editing

Comment: @LudovicZenohateLagouardette what is line 1003 of ArchiUtils.hpp? (Also, I suspect the issue might be not be in the code that you're showing us.)

Comment: Please post code and error messages you are getting **when you compile the exact code you have posted**. Do not cut and post a piece of code and error messages generated by compiling full code. See [mcve].

Comment: This doesn't address your problem, but you'll find that your `union` won't work out very well. It contains non-trivial data members.

Answer (score 0):

```
        class session_elem;
        union session_elem_t;
        enum session_elem_type{s,n,c,f,r};
        typedef std::map<std::string, session_elem> autosession;
        union session_elem_t{
            std::string s;
            int64_t n;
            char c;
            std::function<void(autosession*)> f;
            std::map<std::string, session_elem> r;
        };
        class session_elem{
            session_elem_type type;
            session_elem_t* val;
        };
```

Made it work by making session_elem POD by changing `session_elem_t` to `session_elem_t*`.

Made the magic happen.

Answer (score 0):

As the trouble in your original code stems from the declaration of `session_elem_t::f` as `std::function<void(autosession*)> f`,
because it requires a definition of:

```
std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, session_elem>
```

at a point when `session_elem` is undefined, it might be more convenient to you 
(though I can't be sure from the available code) to define `session_elem_t::f` instead 
as simply a function pointer, rather than
replace `session_elem::session_elem_t val` with `session_elem::session_elem_t *val`.
This will compile:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class session_elem;
typedef std::map<std::string, session_elem> autosession;
union session_elem_t{
    std::string s;
    int64_t n;
    char c;
    void (*f)(autosession*);
    autosession r;
};
class session_elem{
    enum type{s,n,c,f,r};
    session_elem_t val;
};
```